# MultipleBrandedFares not returned on production API endpoint

Tags: sabre

My code is working properly on test/cert environment returning multiple branded fares as specified in request. However, when trying on REST production endpoint, I don't get multiple branded fares. Also, in response there is no `Brand` property in `fareComponentDescs`, it is like `MultipleBrandedFares` being completly ignored.

This is my request on production endpoint (Token and PseudoCityCode replaced for security reasons)

```
POST /v3/offers/shop HTTP/1.1
Host: api.havail.sabre.com
Content-Length: 1028
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <my token>
Content-Type: application/json
Conversation-Id: bGcUH2p5ptFkUi3JLrBDXMeYPfWw3Fji
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{
    "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
        "Version": "3",
        "OriginDestinationInformation": [
            {
                "RPH": "0",
                "DepartureDateTime": "2021-09-30T00:00:00",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "MUC"
                },
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "LHR"
                }
            },
            {
                "RPH": "1",
                "DepartureDateTime": "2021-10-20T00:00:00",
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "LHR"
                },
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "MUC"
                }
            }
        ],
        "POS": {
            "Source": [
                {
                    "PseudoCityCode": "<my code>",
                    "RequestorID": {
                        "CompanyName": {
                            "Code": "TN"
                        },
                        "ID": "1",
                        "Type": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "IntelliSellTransaction": {
                "RequestType": {
                    "Name": "100ITINS"
                }
            }
        },
        "TravelPreferences": {
            "Baggage": {
                "CarryOnInfo": true,
                "Description": true,
                "RequestType": "C"
            },
            "CabinPref": [
                {
                    "Cabin": "Y"
                }
            ],
            "ETicketDesired": true,
            "TPA_Extensions": {}
        },
        "TravelerInfoSummary": {
            "AirTravelerAvail": [
                {
                    "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
                        {
                            "Code": "ADT",
                            "Quantity": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "PriceRequestInformation": {
                "TPA_Extensions": {
                    "BrandedFareIndicators": {
                        "MultipleBrandedFares": true,
                        "ReturnBrandAncillaries": true,
                        "UpsellLimit": 2
                    }
                }
            },
            "SeatsRequested": [
                1
            ]
        },
        "AvailableFlightsOnly": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Branded Fares requires activation, is possible that is ignored because you don't have enabled this functionality.
Is possible to be enabled in CERT due to be for testing purpose.

To activate contact the account executive.